# Can't make batch string comparison work

Tags: batch-file

I'm sorry that this question has been asked multiple times and I'm re-asking it, but the truth is I've tried every possible thing and it just doesn't want to work!

```
@echo off
echo This is a test batch file
echo What colour would you like?
set "colour="
set /p colour =
if "%colour%"==red color c
if "%colour%"==blue color b
PAUSE
```

I've tried with

```
set /p "colour"=
```

or

```
set /p "colour"="%colour%"
```

or

```
if "%colour%" == "red" color b
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Seems impossible to get it tho lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p colour=
if "%colour%"=="red" color c
```

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

Since LHS of the comparison is `"quoted"`, so must be the RHS for a match to appear

Tip: `/i` will make the match case-insensitive.